# React Native CSS Absolute styling, seems backwards

Tags: css, react-native

I have a heart I am trying to put on the very bottom right of the container (imageView). But it is putting it on the left side for some reason. I have been hacking away at the styles forever and can't figure out why. Any help is very appreciated.

Image of what it looks like: [image]

```
<View style={styles.imageView}>
    <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
    <View style={styles.dates}>
        <AppText style={styles.postedDate}>Posted: {getParsedDate(posted)}</AppText>
        <AppText style={styles.expDate}>Expires: {getParsedDate(expiration)}</AppText>
    </View>
    <Image
       style={styles.image}
       source={image}
    ></Image>
    <View style={user ? styles.heart : styles.none}>
         <Heart indexStore={indexStore} db={db} auth={auth} />
    </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dates: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  expDate: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginHorizontal: "3%",
  },
  heart: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  image: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  imageView: {
    flex: 1.5,
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",  
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  postedDate: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginHorizontal: "3%",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: "serif",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: you should try margin-left: auto

Comment: Oh gosh I just figured it out, something not even in this code. In my Heart component, for the heart image I was setting width, but not height. For some reason once I set the height, the absolute positioning for it in THIS code worked. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. I feel like i'll never get the hang of css :(

Comment: Although React Native's layout system looks similar to and shares many qualities with it, it is not actually CSS -- it's a layout system called FlexBox.